# How to convert a vertical string to a horizontal one?

Tags: python, string, replace, split, transpose

how can I convert a vertical string into a horizontal one in Python?

I tried:

```
result=astring.replace("\n", "")
```

but it doesn't do anything, it remains vertical..

The code is the following:

```
names = "".join(name).replace("\n","")
print(names)
```

where "names" is:

```
Federica        
Silvio
Enrico
```

I would like:

```
Federica, Silvio, Enrico
```

Comment: Think again about your problem considering to use a list of names. Convert string to a list of names, then convert the list into a string the format you want. But we don't do homework.

Comment: ``"it doesn't do nothing"``, so it did do something

Comment: Please `print(repr(names))` and put what is displayed in your question (instead) of what you have now as 'where "names" is:'

Answer (score 1):

```
x = """Federica
Silvio
Enrico"""
x.replace("\n",', ')
```

> 'Federica, Silvio, Enrico'

Your method is fundamentally wrong, when you apply a function, it combines a iterables with spaces in the middle. e.g.

```
" ".join("hello")
```

> 'h e l l o'

So when you call it on a string with no join value, the string is unchanged. Then you replace '\n' with '', which will flatten the string but not insert the comma.

Comment: It's worth noting that ``x.replace(...)`` will not modify ``x``, because strings are immutable. Instead it will return a new modified string object.

Comment: Considering that in the question, the OP assigned the value to names, I omitted this fact.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the names in a string format, for example:

```
names = """Federica
Silvio
Enrico"""
```

You can split the vertical string into an horizontal string using replace:

```
result = names.replace("\n", ", ")
```

Which results in:

```
print(results)
'Federica, Silvio, Enrico'
```

From this, I can say your approach was not wrong, maybe you were not storing the result of the replace? Replace does not modify the string but returns a new one with the operation performed.